# Can I upload a font to ShareLatex once and use in several projects?

Tags: fonts, editors, sharelatex, online, xepersian

I should write several Persian latex documents. So I need upload a Persian font and use it. Is there a way to upload the font just once. Is there another online LaTeX editor which provide this?
Here is a simple of my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\settextfont[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont={*},
  BoldFont={*Bd},
  ItalicFont={*It},
  BoldItalicFont={*BdIt},
]{XB Niloofar}
\begin{document}
.در برسی حرکت هر ذره باید یک چارچوب مرجع تعین کنیم
\end{document}
```

My fonts are "XB Niloofar" , "XB NiloofarBd", "XB NiloofarIt", XB NiloofarBdIt".

Comment: You need to have the fonts present at your project folder. So if you upload it once, it would be there until you remove it. What do you mean just once?  Do you mean for different projects?

Comment: @NEO Yes. Each project want fonts separately.

Comment: Each project is completely separated on sharelatex and you cannot share a file among them, which makes sense.
So you need to upload your fonts for each project separately.

Comment: By the way, I think this is the case for other similar tools, and none of them would give you the feature you want. Because you have to either install the fonts in your system, so they would be in your path when you compile; or put them near your tex files. The first option is out of choice because you cannot install anything on their systems, and each project may be compiled on different systems. So the only option is the second one.

Comment: This is something we (ShareLaTeX) are going to look at in 2016.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the request was recorded by ShareLaTeX staff and, as of now, ShareLaTeX has merged with overleaf